# How to debug a query in extbase?

Tags: mysql, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-6.2.x

```
$query = $this->createQuery();

    return $query->matching($query->like('linker', "$linkerKey=$linkerValue"))
        ->setOrderings(array('crdate' => $ordering))
        ->execute();
```

How can i debug such a generated query in extbase? When creating the same query again (but without the execute() ) and trying to display it with var_dump or the internal t3lib_div::debug i just receive a blank page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$result = $query->matching($query->like('linker', "$linkerKey=$linkerValue"))
   ->setOrderings(array('crdate' => $ordering))
   ->execute();

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOutput = true;

return $result;
```

Comment: This does not work for me at all. What is $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOutput = true; supposed to do? I get no results. I am using TYPO3 4.6.6 here and can not get the SQL generated by Extbase. Why is that so difficult?

Comment: @Martin: See http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/47/html/init_8php.html#a1f027650f1101a18b9881ddd801559f4

Comment: To extend: you can also assign `1` (same as `true`, for `display queries with errors`) or `2` (for `display all queries`).

Comment: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOutput = 2;` is NOT working... i dont understand why it is such a hassle to simply enable output of sql-queries...

Answer (score 44):

In version **8.7** or newer another way needs to be taken:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;

$queryParser = $this->objectManager->get(Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
$queryBuilder = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query);

DebuggerUtility::var_dump($queryBuilder->getSQL());
DebuggerUtility::var_dump($queryBuilder->getParameters());
```

Comment: Excellent!, That indeed helps in finding what is running behind.

Comment: Why isn't this directly built into the DebuggerUtility?!

Comment: Thanks. Those lines will be holy for me.

Comment: I think the executable SQL statement is needed.

    `$queryParser = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
$sql = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query)->getSQL();
$paramters = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query)->getParameters();
$search = array();
$replace = array();
foreach ($paramters as $k => $v) {
    $search[] = ':' . $k;
    $replace[] = '\'' . $v . '\'';
}
$sql = str_replace($search, $replace, $sql);
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($sql);
`

Comment: pgampe, @FranzHolzinger, basing on your answers I created an abstract repository as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63231511/1066240), I'm interested of your opinion and maybe fixes and testing in the previous TYPO3 versions.

Answer (score 8):

**This information is outdated and deprecated in TYPO3 8.7 and I'm only leaving the answer up for reference. Refer to @pgampe 's answer on how debug extbase queries in more recent versions of TPYO3.**

Extbase now has a QueryParser for that. In your repository method, right before returning the executed query, insert:

```
    $parser = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Storage\\Typo3DbQueryParser');  
    $queryParts = $parser->parseQuery($query); 
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($queryParts, 'query');
```

The result is a table view of the query parts, split by SQL keywords, e.g.:

[image: table view of the query in question]

*Keep in mind that the QueryResult that your Repository returns may still be different from the SQL query result. Extbase uses the PropertyMapper to try to convert every result row into an ExtbaseObject. If the PropertyMapper is misconfigured or the row contains data that cannot be converted to the data types according to the configuration, these Objects will silently be skipped.*

Comment: On version 8.7 this gives my an error: `Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::parseQuery()`

Comment: As @pgampe pointed out, this method is deprecated. See his answer for an update.

Comment: O.K now debug a query that is generated in one of the core files like this: $this->xyRepository->add($xyObject);

Answer (score 5):

This hack to extbase is dirty, but useful:

In typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php
edit the method buildQuery(array $sql) 
before the return statement, add:

```
t3lib_div::debug($statement, 'SQL Query Extbase');
```

Remove after use, and don't forget this will affect everything that runs on extbase, so use in dev environment only

Source: http://sancer-media.net/2011/extbase-schneller-mysql-debug.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Note, in TYPO3 6.1 this is at typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php - but the hack doesn't work anymore

Comment: See @biesior's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084863/extbase-get-created-sql-from-query for 6.1 - works

Answer (score 1):

An easy way without changing any Typo3 core code and not mentioned in any forum so far is using the php "serialize()" method:

```
$result = $query->execute();
echo (serialize($result));
```

In the result object you find the SQL query (look for "statement;" ...)

Answer (score 1):

In v6.2x or later, you can debug result object in extBase like:

In repository:

> return $query->execute(true); // "true" will return array result

Or also you can debug result object in Controller:

> $resultObject = $this->yourRepository->findAll();
>   \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($resultObject);

Answer (score 1):

This works as long as $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] is supported.
It will show you the complete build SQL query.

```
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $queryResult
 * @param bool $explainOutput
 * @return void
 */
public function debugQuery(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface $queryResult,
    $explainOutput = false
) {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOuput = 2;
    if ($explainOutput) {
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->explainOutput = true;
    }
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->store_lastBuiltQuery = true;
    $queryResult->toArray();
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debug_lastBuiltQuery
    );
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->store_lastBuiltQuery = false;
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->explainOutput = false;
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOuput = false;
}
```

So with that function you can do something like this in your controller:

```
$all = $this->repository->findAll();
$this->repository->debugQuery($all);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [@pgampe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234469/pgampe)'s answer and
[@FranzHolzinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3930829/franz-holzinger)'s comment I created AbstractonRepository in my ext wit some extracted methods, that can be extended in your own repository to bring debug possibility little bit more comfortable.

**NOTE** That's tested and working for TYPO3 ver `10.x`, most probably will work since `8.7+` as well, requires testing.

```php
<?php

namespace VENDOR\Extkey\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface;


/**
 * Class AbstractRepository brings methods for query debugging in TYPO3 ver. 10.x
 * Based on StackOverflow answer by `pgampe` answer and `FranzHolzinger` comment
 * source https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286155/1066240
 *
 * All repositories in this extension should extend it.
 *
 * @author Marcus Biesioroff <biesior@gmail.com>
 * @package VENDOR\Extkey\Domain\Repository
 */
abstract class AbstractRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{


    /**
     * @param mixed       $query TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder | TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query
     * @param string|null $title Optional title for var_dump()
     * @param bool        $replaceParams if true replaces the params in SQL statement with values, otherwise dumps the array of params. @see self::renderDebug()
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function debugQuery($query, string $title = null, bool $replaceParams = true): void
    {
        if ($query instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder) {
            $sql = $query->getSQL();
            $params = $query->getParameters();
            $this->renderDebug($sql, $params, $title, $replaceParams);
        } elseif ($query instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query) {
            $this->parseTheQuery($query, $title, $replaceParams);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unhandled type for SQL query, curently only TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder | TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query can be debugged with ' . static::getRepositoryClassName() . '::debugQuery() method.', 1596458998);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses query and displays debug
     *
     * @param QueryInterface $query Query
     * @param string|null    $title Optional title
     * @param bool           $replaceParams if true replaces the params in SQL statement with values, otherwise dumps the array of params. @see self::renderDebug()
     */
    private function parseTheQuery(QueryInterface $query, string $title = null, $replaceParams = true): void
    {
        /** @var Typo3DbQueryParser $queryParser */
        $queryParser = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::class);

        $sql = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query)->getSQL();
        $params = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query)->getParameters();
        $this->renderDebug($sql, $params, $title, $replaceParams);

    }


    /**
     * Renders the output with DebuggerUtility::var_dump()
     *
     * @param string      $sql Generated SQL
     * @param array       $params Params' array
     * @param string|null $title Optional title for var_dump()
     * @param bool        $replaceParams if true replaces the params in SQL statement with values, otherwise dumps the array of params.
     */
    private function renderDebug(string $sql, array $params, string $title = null, bool $replaceParams = true): void
    {
        if ($replaceParams) {

            $search = array();
            $replace = array();
            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                $search[] = ':' . $k;
                $type = gettype($v);
                if (in_array($type, ['integer'])) {
                    $replace[] = $v;
                } else {
                    $replace[] = '\'' . $v . '\'';
                }
            }
            $sql = str_replace($search, $replace, $sql);
            DebuggerUtility::var_dump($sql, $title);
        } else {
            DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
                [
                    'SQL'        => $sql,
                    'Parameters' => $params
                ],
                $title);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used in your repository like in to ways:

```php
<?php

namespace VENDOR\Extkey\Domain\Repository;


use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;


class FooRepository extends \VENDOR\Extkey\Domain\Repository\AbstractRepository
{

    public function findByName($name)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->matching(
            $query->equals('name', $name)
        );
        $this->debugQuery($query, 'Debug SQL in repository with QueryInterface');
        return $query->execute();
    }

    public function queryByName($name)
    {
        /** @var ConnectionPool $pool */
        $pool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
        $connection = $pool->getConnectionForTable('tx_extkey_domain_model_yourmodel');
        $queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
        $query = $queryBuilder
            ->select('*')
            ->from('tx_extkey_domain_model_yourmodel')
            ->where("name like :name")
            ->setParameter('name', "%{$name}%");

        $this->debugQuery($query, 'Debug SQL in my repository with QueryBuilder');
        return $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: The only drawback is that all the repository classes are forced to derive from AbstractRepository. It would be better to have an external Api Class instead.

Comment: In `renderDebug()` the two arrays should be reversed. Otherwise a ':dcValue12" will partly replace by searching and replacing ':dcValue1'. In reverse order, you can avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Here I post a method you can enter for debugging in any class, making a trait of it would be surely possible too. Authorship and source is mentioned in the comment, Usage too:

```
    /**
    * Render the generated SQL of a query in TYPO3 8
    *
    * @author wp_bube https://www.typo3.net/forum/user-profil/benutzer/zeige/benutzer/wp-bube/
    * @src   https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/125747/
    *
    * Usage: $this->debugQuery($query);
    *
    * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface $query
    * @param bool $format
    * @param bool $exit
    */
    private function debugQuery($query, $format = true, $exit = true)
    {
        function getFormattedSQL($sql_raw)
        {
            if (empty($sql_raw) || !is_string($sql_raw)) {
                return false;
            }
            $sql_reserved_all = array( 'ACCESSIBLE', 'ACTION', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'AGAINST', 'AGGREGATE', 'ALGORITHM', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYSE', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AUTOCOMMIT', 'AUTO_INCREMENT', 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH', 'BACKUP', 'BEGIN', 'BETWEEN', 'BINLOG', 'BOTH', 'BY', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CHANGE', 'CHANGED', 'CHARSET', 'CHECK', 'CHECKSUM', 'COLLATE', 'COLLATION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMMITTED', 'COMPRESSED', 'CONCURRENT', 'CONSTRAINT', 'CONTAINS', 'CONVERT', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'DATABASE', 'DATABASES', 'DAY', 'DAY_HOUR', 'DAY_MINUTE', 'DAY_SECOND', 'DEFINER', 'DELAYED', 'DELAY_KEY_WRITE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTINCTROW', 'DIV', 'DO', 'DROP', 'DUMPFILE', 'DUPLICATE', 'DYNAMIC', 'ELSE', 'ENCLOSED', 'END', 'ENGINE', 'ENGINES', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EVENTS', 'EXECUTE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXTENDED', 'FAST', 'FIELDS', 'FILE', 'FIRST', 'FIXED', 'FLUSH', 'FOR', 'FORCE', 'FOREIGN', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FULLTEXT', 'FUNCTION', 'GEMINI', 'GEMINI_SPIN_RETRIES', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GRANTS', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'HEAP', 'HIGH_PRIORITY', 'HOSTS', 'HOUR', 'HOUR_MINUTE', 'HOUR_SECOND', 'IDENTIFIED', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INFILE', 'INNER', 'INSERT', 'INSERT_ID', 'INSERT_METHOD', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'INVOKER', 'IS', 'ISOLATION', 'JOIN', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'KILL', 'LAST_INSERT_ID', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LEVEL', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINEAR', 'LINES', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGS', 'LOW_PRIORITY', 'MARIA', 'MASTER', 'MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY', 'MASTER_HOST', 'MASTER_LOG_FILE', 'MASTER_LOG_POS', 'MASTER_PASSWORD', 'MASTER_PORT', 'MASTER_USER', 'MATCH', 'MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_ROWS', 'MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS', 'MEDIUM', 'MERGE', 'MINUTE', 'MINUTE_SECOND', 'MIN_ROWS', 'MODE', 'MODIFY', 'MONTH', 'MRG_MYISAM', 'MYISAM', 'NAMES', 'NATURAL', 'NOT', 'NULL', 'OFFSET', 'ON', 'OPEN', 'OPTIMIZE', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONALLY', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUTER', 'OUTFILE', 'PACK_KEYS', 'PAGE', 'PARTIAL', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONS', 'PASSWORD', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIVILEGES', 'PROCEDURE', 'PROCESS', 'PROCESSLIST', 'PURGE', 'QUICK', 'RAID0', 'RAID_CHUNKS', 'RAID_CHUNKSIZE', 'RAID_TYPE', 'RANGE', 'READ', 'READ_ONLY', 'READ_WRITE', 'REFERENCES', 'REGEXP', 'RELOAD', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPEATABLE', 'REPLACE', 'REPLICATION', 'RESET', 'RESTORE', 'RESTRICT', 'RETURN', 'RETURNS', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'ROW_FORMAT', 'SECOND', 'SECURITY', 'SELECT', 'SEPARATOR', 'SERIALIZABLE', 'SESSION', 'SET', 'SHARE', 'SHOW', 'SHUTDOWN', 'SLAVE', 'SONAME', 'SOUNDS', 'SQL', 'SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL', 'SQL_BIG_RESULT', 'SQL_BIG_SELECTS', 'SQL_BIG_TABLES', 'SQL_BUFFER_RESULT', 'SQL_CACHE', 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', 'SQL_LOG_BIN', 'SQL_LOG_OFF', 'SQL_LOG_UPDATE', 'SQL_LOW_PRIORITY_UPDATES', 'SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE', 'SQL_NO_CACHE', 'SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE', 'SQL_SAFE_UPDATES', 'SQL_SELECT_LIMIT', 'SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER', 'SQL_SMALL_RESULT', 'SQL_WARNINGS', 'START', 'STARTING', 'STATUS', 'STOP', 'STORAGE', 'STRAIGHT_JOIN', 'STRING', 'STRIPED', 'SUPER', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TEMPORARY', 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TO', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTIONAL', 'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'UNCOMMITTED', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USAGE', 'USE', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VARIABLES', 'VIEW', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WITH', 'WORK', 'WRITE', 'XOR', 'YEAR_MONTH' );

            $sql_skip_reserved_words = array('AS', 'ON', 'USING');
            $sql_special_reserved_words = array('(', ')');
            $sql_raw = str_replace("\n", " ", $sql_raw);
            $sql_formatted = "";
            $prev_word = "";
            $word = "";
            for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($sql_raw); $i < $j; $i++) {
                $word .= $sql_raw[$i];
                $word_trimmed = trim($word);
                if ($sql_raw[$i] == " " || in_array($sql_raw[$i], $sql_special_reserved_words)) {
                    $word_trimmed = trim($word);
                    $trimmed_special = false;
                    if (in_array($sql_raw[$i], $sql_special_reserved_words)) {
                        $word_trimmed = substr($word_trimmed, 0, -1);
                        $trimmed_special = true;
                    }
                    $word_trimmed = strtoupper($word_trimmed);
                    if (in_array($word_trimmed, $sql_reserved_all) && !in_array($word_trimmed, $sql_skip_reserved_words)) {
                        if (in_array($prev_word, $sql_reserved_all)) {
                            $sql_formatted .= '<b>' . strtoupper(trim($word)) . '</b>' . '&nbsp;';
                        } else {
                            $sql_formatted .= '<br/>&nbsp;';
                            $sql_formatted .= '<b>' . strtoupper(trim($word)) . '</b>' . '&nbsp;';
                        }
                        $prev_word = $word_trimmed;
                        $word = "";
                    } else {
                        $sql_formatted .= trim($word) . '&nbsp;';
                        $prev_word = $word_trimmed;
                        $word = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            $sql_formatted .= trim($word);
            return $sql_formatted;
        }

        $queryParser          = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
        $doctrineQueryBuilder = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query);
        $preparedStatement    = $doctrineQueryBuilder->getSQL();
        $parameters           = $doctrineQueryBuilder->getParameters();
        $stringParams = [];
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $parameter) {
            $stringParams[':' . $key] = $parameter;
        }
        $statement = strtr($preparedStatement, $stringParams);
        if ($format) {
            echo '<code>' . getFormattedSQL($statement) . '</code>';
        } else {
            echo $statement;
        }
        if ($exit) {
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I build a static function of a utilitiee class for the  use in TYPO3 9.5.
it should work in TYPO3 10.4. and TYPO3 11

```
<?php

namespace MyExtension\MyVendor\Utilities;

/**
 * used in TYPO3 9.5.x
 */

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;

class DebugQueryUtilities
{
 
    public static function checkExtbaseQuery($query)
    {

        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $queryParser = $objectManager->get(Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
        /** @var QueryBuilder $doctrineQuery */
        $doctrineQuery = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query);
        $result = $doctrineQuery->getSQL();
        $params = $doctrineQuery->getParameters();
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
            $result
        ); // generate an output in the frontpage
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
            $params
        );
        return [$result, $params]; // make result vieable with xDebug
    }

}
```

Use in Repository

```
...
        [$sql,$params] = DebugQueryUtilities::checkExtbaseQuery($query);
        return $query->execute()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed @biesior ´s answer:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace YOUR\NAMESPACE\HERE;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface;

class Debug
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $query TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder | TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public static function debugQuery(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query $query): void
    {
        $sql = self::getQuerySql($query);
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug(
            $var = $sql,
            $header = '',
            $group = 'Debug'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param QueryInterface $query Query
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public static function getQuerySql(QueryInterface $query): string
    {
        if ($query instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder) {
            $sql = $query->getSQL();
            $params = $query->getParameters();
            $executeableSql = self::replaceQueryParams($sql, $params);
        } elseif ($query instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query) {
            /** @var Typo3DbQueryParser $queryParser */
            //$queryParser = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
            $queryParser = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
            $sql = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query)->getSQL();
            $params = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query)->getParameters();
            $executeableSql = self::replaceQueryParams($sql, $params);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Unhandled type for SQL query, curently only TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder | TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query can be debugged with ' . static::getRepositoryClassName() . '::debugQuery() method.', 1596458998);
        }
        return $executeableSql;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sql Generated SQL
     * @param array $params Params' array
     * @return string
     */
    private static function replaceQueryParams(string $sql, array $params): string
    {
        $search = array();
        $replace = array();
        foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
            $search[] = ':' . $k;
            $type = gettype($v);
            if (in_array($type, ['integer'])) {
                $replace[] = $v;
            } else {
                // escape \ (eg in TYPO3 STI)
                $v = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $v);
                $replace[] = '\'' . $v . '\'';
            }
        }
        $sql = str_replace($search, $replace, $sql);
        return $sql;
    }
}
```