# Extbase - get created sql from query

Tags: sql, typo3, extbase

i want to get some database tables from my typo3 extensions.
The Extension is based on extbase.

The query always returns nothing but the data exists

I've tried this:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement('SELECT * FROM `my_table`
    WHERE field = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1',
    array($condition));

$results = $query->execute();
```

and this:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();

$query->matching($query->equals('field', $condition));
$query->setOrderings(array('date' => Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING));
$query->setLimit(1);

$results = $query->execute();
```

both returns *null* as result.

Is it possible to get the sql that the class creates to look where the bug is?

I've looked in some extbase persistent classes but didn't find a clue

EDIT: 
For those who are interested.. i found a "solution".

If you create the query with the statement() method, you can print the query with this function

```
echo $query->getStatement()->getStatement();
```

It doesn't replace the placeholder.
But you can get the Variables with this method

```
var_dump($query->getStatement()->getBoundVariables());
```

Thats the best Solution that i found, without editing the extbase extenstions

Comment: You could also use Zend Server, it's "Z-Ray" collects all database quries automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug a query in extbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075296/how-to-debug-a-query-in-extbase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/55225/), although it's not very comfortable in use it helps a lot:

in general you need this code at the end of the `buildQuery(array $sql)` method (*) - right before `return $statement;`

```
if (in_array("your_table_name", $sql['tables'])) {
    var_dump($statement);
    print_r($statement);
}
```

(*) Class file:

- TYPO3 ver.: 4.x: `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php`
- TYPO3 ver.: 6.x: `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php`

---

#### In 6.2.x ...

You can try within `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection::exec_SELECTquery` method, just add the condition after fetching the $query, like (*trim is important!*):

```
public function exec_SELECTquery($select_fields, $from_table, $where_clause, $groupBy = '', $orderBy = '', $limit = '') {
    $query = $this->SELECTquery($select_fields, $from_table, $where_clause, $groupBy, $orderBy, $limit);

    if (trim($from_table) == 'fe_users') {
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump($query);
    }

// rest of method
```

Comment: is there no simple solution for this problem? something like $query->getRawSql()

Comment: I don't know such... If it was I would describe it in first place. I'm using that way as described and didn't find anything better.

Comment: @Mateng: Believe, it allows to save a lot of time :) I'm using this to for an example validating things like the findPrevious()... method :)

Comment: I can no longer find the `buildQuery` method in 6.2

Answer (score 6):

In TYPO3 6.2 you can use Extbase DebuggerUtility to debug the query.

Add this code before $query->execute():

```
$queryParser = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Storage\\Typo3DbQueryParser');
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($queryParser->parseQuery($query));
```

For TYPO3 8.7+ use this code instead:

```
$queryParser = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtilityGeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbQueryParser::class);
$doctrineQueryBuilder = $queryParser->convertQueryToDoctrineQueryBuilder($query);
$doctrineQueryBuilderSQL = $doctrineQueryBuilder->getSQL();
$doctrineQueryBuilderParameters = $doctrineQueryBuilder->getParameters();
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way without changing any Typo3 core code and not mentioned in any forum so far is using the php "serialize()" method:

```
$result = $query->execute();
echo (serialize($result));
```

In the result object you find the SQL query ("statement;" ...)

Answer (score 2):

Improvement to biesiors answer:

As Extbase replaces some placeholders after calling buildQuery(), you might prefer to place the debug output into `getObjectDataByQuery()`, just after *$this->replacePlaceholders($sql, $parameters, $tableName);*

```
if (strpos($sql, "your_table_name.")) {
    debug($sql, 'my debug output');
};
```

Also, better use debug() instead of var_dump().
[File: `typo3\sysext\extbase\Classes\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbBackend.php`. Line 339 in version 6.1]:

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);
$getHotelInfo = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE field = ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1';
return $query->statement($getHotelInfo)->execute();
```

For executing query you have to write 'setReturnQueryResult' on your repository

Answer (score 0):

I just extended the above snippet, with a $_GET condition.
for debugging, just append "?dbg_table=tx_some_of_my_tables" to your address, and you're ready to go ;-)

```
if (in_array($_GET['dbg_table'], $sql['tables'])) {
        echo('<div style="background: #ebebeb; border: 1px solid #999; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px;"><pre style="white-space: normal">'.$statement.'</pre></div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to debug your statements when using TYPO3 6.1 is to use the [query parser](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/61/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_storage_1_1_typo3_db_backend.html#a5a4c024e2559069da301c85fb297b0e7) of `Typo3DbBackend`.

```
$parser = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Storage\\Typo3DbBackend');
$params = array();
$queryParts = $parser->parseQuery($query, $params);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::devLog('query', 'my_extension', 1, array('query' => $queryParts, 'params' => $params));
```

The parser returns an array containing the different parts of the generated SQL statement.

With TYPO3 6.2 the `parseQuery` method was moved to [`Typo3DbQueryParser`](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_storage_1_1_typo3_db_query_parser.html#aa2918c5df37389fa5cf2f9939bea5f28) and lost its second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest set this in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php file under 'SYS' array

```
'SYS' => array(
......
'displayErrors' => 1,
'sqlDebug' => 1
.......
)
```

and then write wrong field name in query intentionally and then execute code.
this will show last query execute with error.