# TYPO3 Extbase: Access to external data sources (Typo3 "pages" table)

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I'm actually writing an extension for an xml export of my pagetree and the content elements.
With the following example I've mapped the typo3 "pages" table on my Page model:

```
# typo3conf/ext/my_publisher/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt
# Module configuration
module.tx_mypublisher.persistence.classes {
  Tx_MyPublisher_Domain_Model_Page {
    mapping {
      tableName = pages
      recordType = Tx_MyPublisher_Domain_Model_Page
      columns {
        uid.mapOnProperty =         uid
        pid.mapOnProperty =         pid
        sorting.mapOnProperty =     sorting
        deleted.mapOnProperty =     deleted
        title.mapOnProperty =       title
        is_siteroot.mapOnProperty = is_siteroot
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the pages in my controller...

```
$pages = $this->pageRepository->findAll();
```

This function provides me the result of my model table which is empty until now.
So I think I need some "initialize" method in my repository that fills my model table,
but until now I've no approach how I can solve this.

Has anyone a solution approach for this problem?

I work with Typo3 6.1.1.

*Excuse my English i know it's not the best*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**:  remove `recordType = Tx_MyPublisher_Domain_Model_Page` from your mapping, it causes that your repo contains only records which was created as YOUR page, and I assume, that you want to gat *any* page(s) . Literally, it includes condition to your statement like (*depending TCA settings*) `AND record_type = 'Tx_MyPublisher_Domain_Model_Page'`...

**Second**: make sure that the `storagePid` is `IGNORED` in all your queries, if you'll force some `storagePid` by TypoScript you'll get only subpages of given page... The easiest way to do that is avoiding `storagePid` in whole repo, add this method to your `PageRepository`

```
public function initializeObject() {
    $this->defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->create('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
    $this->defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
}
```

**Third**: Use [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13085297/1066240) for checking queries for `pages` table, it isn't comfortable, however it's the fastest way to find why your repo doesn't get required data (just copy the statement and paste it tou your favorite DB GUI).

(*preferably, paste it to your question, so we will can see what's wrong*)

If there are some questions marks like `AND pages.pid = ?` in the debugged statement of course you need to replace them with required value `AND pages.pid = 123`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a storagePid, since your findAll-query relies on that.

```
# TS
plugin.tx_yourext {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_yourext.persistence.storagePid}
    }
}

# Or in query
$query->getQuerySettings()->setStoragePageIds(array($yourId);
```

In your case it could be 0 or whatever page you want to start your export with. But that will only give you pages that are children of the page with the storagePid as its uid. If you want to export a whole pagetree, you need a recursive function. Also you have to get a relation between your content elements and your page.

Comment: ok I've the storagePid set to 0 and then 2 (which is my root page) in TS
But in both cases, nothing happened.
Is there nothing else to configure in the TCA? Or is there any function that i need in the repository to get data from the pages table?

Comment: Are you using a backend module? TypoScript doesn't work there. In this you must work with the configuration manager or just set your storage pid in your repository.

Comment: ah ok yes I use a backend module... but the tableMapping works there?

Comment: Have a look at the configuration manager http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/ConfigurationManager_rework

Comment: I've done this $frameworkConfiguration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);

But the TypoScript looks fine! Everything I've configuration is available.

Comment: btw: ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK also gives me a correct result
(storagePid ist set and also my table mapping)