# TYPO3 6.1: Extbase mapping

Tags: mapping, typo3, extbase

I try to map the `tx_formhandler_log`. But it just wont work.

At the ext_tables.php i call

```
$tmp_columns = Array (
    "checkbox" => Array (
        "exclude" => 1,
        "label" => "exported",
        "config" => Array (
            "type" => "check",
            "size" => "1",
        )
    ),
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tx_formhandler_log', $tmp_columns, 1);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_formhandler_log','checkbox;;;;1-1-1');
```

also i still added in the ext_typoscript_setup.txt

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            TYPO3\MyExt\Domain\Model\Log {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_formhandler_log
                    recordType =
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

At `\TYPO3\MyExt\Domain\Model\Log` there are all setter an getter.

The same configuration works in other extension, but not at mine. At my extension i have a working `pages` mapping, but the `tx_formhandler_log`-mapping wont work.

I do not understand, what i have forgotten. Can somebody helps me?

Comment: Try to check if it queries the table at all ie. like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13085297/1066240 . If it tries to fetch anything from `tx_formhandler_log` copy the statement and try to run it in DB gui.

Also remove `rcordType =` at all, as you probably don't have own record type there

Comment: Thx for your advise! It was not a wrong query, it was the wrong order of the extensionlist. In the moment i want to extend `tx_formhandler_log`, the formhandler-extension was not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I wrote in the comment: It was the wrong order in the extensionlist. In the moment i want to extend `tx_formhandler_log`, the `formhandler`-extension was not included. I change the order and everything works very well.